# copying a value inside a map of <td> using a button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to achieve a `copy` buttuon to copy the value/text inside the td of my table.

The problem is whenever the `copyFunction` triggers, it throws me an error `copyText.select() is not a function`

Here is my copyFunction..

```
function copyFunction() {
    // Get the text field
    var copyText = document.getElementById("availCode").text;
    console.log(copyText)
    // Select the text field
    copyText.select();
    copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999); // For mobile devices

    // Copy the text inside the text field
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText.text);

    // Alert the copied text
    alert("Copied the text: " + copyText.text);
  }
```

and here is my `<tr>`

```
<tr key={key} className="bg-white border-b dark:bg-gray-800 dark:border-gray-700">
                  <td className="px-6 py-4 font-medium text-gray-900 whitespace-nowrap dark:text-white">
                    {key + (pagesVisited - usersPerPage) + 1}{" "}
                  </td>
                  <th scope="row"className="flex items-center px-6 py-4 text-gray-900 whitespace-nowrap dark:text-white"
                  >
                    <div className="pl-3">
                      <td
                        className="text-base font-semibold"
                        value={tempoArray}
                        id="availCode"
                      >
                        {tempoArray}
                      </td>
                    </div>
                  </th>
                  <td className="px-6 py-4 font-medium text-gray-900 whitespace-nowrap dark:text-white">
                    <div className="flex items-center gap-1">
                      <div className="flex h-2.5 w-2.5 rounded-full bg-green-500"></div>
                      <div className="text-lg text-black"></div>
                      {"AVAILABLE"}
                    </div>{" "}
                  </td>
                  <td className="px-6 py-4 font-medium text-gray-900 whitespace-nowrap dark:text-white">
                    <div className="flex items-center justify-evenly">
                      <button
                        onClick={copyFunction}
                        className="text-white bg-green-700 hover:bg-red-800 focus:outline-none focus:ring-4 focus:ring-red-300 font-medium rounded-full text-sm px-5 py-2.5 text-center mr-2 mb-2 dark:bg-red-600 dark:hover:bg-red-700 dark:focus:ring-red-900"
                      >
                        Copy
                      </button>
                      <button
                        type="button"
                        className="text-white bg-red-700 hover:bg-red-800 focus:outline-none focus:ring-4 focus:ring-red-300 font-medium rounded-full text-sm px-5 py-2.5 text-center mr-2 mb-2 dark:bg-red-600 dark:hover:bg-red-700 dark:focus:ring-red-900"
                      >
                        Delete
                      </button>
                    </div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
```

EDIT:
Whenever I try to click the button `copy` it console.log the value that I am trying to copy. However it still does copy and paste using the keyboard commands.

Comment: First, if you are using a UI library, please use that only. Do not use DOM selectors. Second, You should have all the values as a part of variables. Use them and compute output

Answer (score 0):

If you are using reactjs then do not use DOM values like the way you have implemented.
Just implement the below code while user trigger onclick on button,

```
onClick={() =>
      navigator.clipboard
        .writeText(text that you want to copy)
        .then(() => {
          console.log('Code copied');
        })
        .catch(e => {
          console.error(`code copy failed `, e);
        })
    }
```